# Употребление словосочетания "могут похвастаться"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать: «Не все достопримечательности могут похвастаться своим внешним видом»?

Answer (score 1):

Только если Вы хотите быть оригинальной и при условии, что возьмете слово *похвастаться* в кавычки:

**Не все достопримечательности могут "похвастаться" своим внешним видом.**